# Looping over two dataframes of same size and calculating correlation

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, indexing, correlation

Apologies in advance, as I am new to R. I'm attempting to calculate the correlation coefficient for each cortical measurement per ROI from two dataframes. The two dataframes are `df3` and `df5`.

They both look something like this:

```
> df3

SubjID     SeshLab           L_Frontal     R_Frontal
123456     2016-06-03        2.54          2.78
135791     2016-07-21        2.39          2.49
147036     2016-12-03        2.67          2.39

> df5
SubjID     SeshLab           L_Frontal     R_Frontal
123456     2016-06-03        2.45          2.87
135791     2016-07-21        2.93          2.94
147036     2016-12-03        2.76          2.93
```

And I'm trying to obtain a dataframe that looks like this:

```
SubjID     SeshLab           L_Frontal                      R_Frontal
123456     2016-06-03        corr.test(2.54 and 2.45)       corr.test(2.78 and 2.87)
135791     2016-07-21        corr.test(2.39 and 2.93)       corr.test(2.49 and 2.94)
147036     2016-12-03        corr.test(2.67 and 2.76)       corr.test(2.39 and 2.93)
```

I've attempted to write the loop to match indices since the dataframes are the same size.

```
correlation_results = list()

for (i in 3:df3$SubjID)
{
 x = as.numeric(df3[1,i])
 y = as.numeric(df5[1,i])
 correlation_results <- cor.test(x,y,method="spearman")
 
}

numerical expression has 110 elements: only the first usedError in cor.test.default(x, y, method = "spearman") : 
  not enough finite observations
```

```
for (i in df3$SubjID)
{
 x = as.numeric(df3[i,i])
 y = as.numeric(df5[i,i])
 correlation_results <- cor.test(x,y,method="spearman")
 
}
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `107516` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How do I index the two dataframes properly to get this result?

Comment: This doesn't make statistical sense. You can't calculate correlation or perform a correlation test on just two numbers at a time.  So maybe you should first rethink your analysis approach. If you need statistical advice, you can ask for help at [stats.se]

Comment: But to get the loop to run, you'd need something like `for (i in 3:ncol(df3))`  or `for(i in 3:nrow(df3))` (It's not clear which you are trying to do exactly) since you are iterating over the indexes and not the values.

Comment: It's helpful to provide some of your data via `dput()`, so that we can reproduce the issue. For each df, you can do  `dput(head(df3))`, then paste the results for each.